# How to check and compare the date range php

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to compare two dates, the current time and whether it is smaller than the dates I set.
Unfortunately, the condition does not want to work in any way

```
function is_store_open_to_thursday($html, $product)
{
    date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Warsaw');

    $datetime1 = new DateTimeImmutable('thursday 12:00:00');
    $datetime2 = $datetime1->modify('+3 days');
    $now = time();
    $html = '<form action="' . esc_url($product->add_to_cart_url()) . '" class="cart" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">';
    $html .= woocommerce_quantity_input(array(), $product, false);


    if ($now >= strtotime($datetime1) && $now <= strtotime($datetime2)) {
        $html .= '<p>WORK</p>';
    }
    else{
        $html .= 'NOT WORKING';
    }

    $html .= '</form>';
    return $html;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Variables `$datetime1` and `datetime2` are objects.
So if you pass them to function [`strtotime`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) you will should to see in your php.log file warnings:

`<b>Warning</b>:  strtotime() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given in`.

Change yor conditions statement to:

```
if ($now >= $datetime1->getTimestamp() && $now <= $datetime2->getTimestamp())
```

Comment: Could you tell me, how to set the range so that every Thursday at 12 to every Sunday at 12 o'clock it works correctly

Comment: i pasted another answer.

Answer (score 1):

It's not very cool, but should works:

```
$now = new \DateTime();
$startDate = new \DateTimeImmutable("Thursday 12:00:00");
$endDate = $startDate->modify("+3 days");

if(
    ($now->format("N H:i:s") >= $startDate->format("N 12:00:00"))
    && ($now->format("N H:i:s") <= $endDate->format("N 12:00:00"))
) {
    echo "Date in range!";
} else {
    echo "Date out of range!";
}
```